# Unity 2D how to animate X position without messing with Y?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity 2D. I have several sprites (clouds) that should float nicely in the sky. Basically the animation is the same - they go from the right to the left (change their X position), but at a different Y positions. I can't figure out if it is possible to achieve this with one animation/animator of should I create separate animations for each cloud?

So far I failed with reusing one animator as they always collapse to the same Y position. So I ended up with creating separate animations for each cloud, but this looks a little weird. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use animator/animation technic - you can use single animator and animation clip, but you need to remove Y pos property from animation, just like on picture, here we have only X variable

[image]

Comment: Actually this doesn't work for me cause it only means that X coordinate is animated, but it doesn't mean that Y and Z coordinates could be different.

Comment: @MaximLavrov isn't a different Y and Z value exactly what you asked for? With this approach you can set different Y and Z values and it will stay there, only animating the X value. It might however behave unexpected due to perspective

Answer (score 0):

The Animator writes the Transform of the Object, if you use the same animation clip for all the clouds they will follow the same path you just set in the animation. That's the reason why all your clouds share the same Y position; as @Ivzhenko Oleksii say you need to remove the Y property in the animation Clip.

You can use a script that will look something like this:

```
void CloudAnimation()
{
 offset += Time.deltaTime;
 newCloudPos = new Vector3 (ActualCloudPos.x - offset, ActualCloudPos.y, ActualCloudPos.z);

 ActualCloudPos = newCloudPos;
}
```

This way your cloud will move in X axis right to left.
When your cloud reach some point out of your screeen you need todo something like this:

```
 ActualCloudPos = new Vector3(PlayerPos.x + 30f, RandomValueinY, 1f);
```

This way your cloud will appear 30 units in front of your player and thanks to the function "CloudAnimation" it will start his travel across ths screen looking like it is moving.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I consider making a programmatic solution, but I was curious if it is possible with standard animation/animator.